# I want to have the image at the top, while the button and the text are in the center. I don't know how to do it

Tags: flutter

In this code, what i'm trying to do is to put the image at the top. I tried to align the image at the top while the other two are in the center, but it didn't work.

Here is the code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:velneoapp/dialogos/exit_dialog.dart';
import 'package:velneoapp/routes/constants.dart';

class EntradaView extends StatelessWidget {
  const EntradaView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Página de Entrada'),
        actions: [
          Tooltip(
            message: "Salir de la aplicación",
            child: IconButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  final shouldExit = await showExitDialog(context);
                  if (shouldExit) {
                    SystemNavigator.pop();
                    exit(
                        0); //TODO Peligroso, por si las dudas, que al parecer a Apple no le gusta.
                  }
                },
                icon: const Icon(Icons.exit_to_app)),
          )
        ],
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
                child: Image.asset("assets/images/placeholder.png")),
            const Text(
              'Bienvenido/a',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 32),
            ElevatedButton.icon(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.login),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamedAndRemoveUntil(
                  context,
                  eleccionRoute,
                  (route) => false,
                );
              },
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                padding:
                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32, vertical: 16),
              ),
              label: const Text(
                'Entrar',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[What the code does now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Y0Pv.png)

I tried to rearrange everything so it goes on the top, but it always does the same. Everything goes in the top or the center.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Appbar'),
  ),
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
          child: Image.network('https://fakeimg.pl/600x400'),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
          child: Column(
        children: [
          const Text(
            'Bienvenido/a',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
          const SizedBox(height: 32),
          ElevatedButton.icon(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.login),
            onPressed: () {},
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 32, vertical: 16),
            ),
            label: const Text(
              'Entrar',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      )),
    ],
  ),
);
```